# How do I show changes that have been made to the develop branch since the last rebase of my feature branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

Using the git flow model, I've got a feature branch that was split from the develop branch at some point in the past. While I'm working on my feature branch, other developers commit to the develop branch. As a result, I'll occasionally perform a rebase to pull these changes into my feature branch.

My question is, how can I get a diff of changes that have been made to the develop branch since the last time I rebased? I.e., "Is my feature branch up to date with the develop branch, and if not, what am I missing?" or perhaps, "If I do a rebase now, what will I get?"

Here's what I've got so far:

Find the commit where we branched:

```
git merge-base feature/my_feature develop
```

Find the diff between that commit and develop's HEAD:

```
git diff <id from above> develop
```

I can easily merge these into a single command:

```
git diff $(git merge-base feature/mybuys develop) develop
```

But that seems rather roundabout. Is there a better way to do this in one shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the triple dots are for:

```
git diff feature/mybuys...develop
```

Comment: Ah cripes, I was totally overthinking it. This is perfect, thanks!